# Stored value type does not match pointer operand type! - store i64, swift.bridge, dictionaryUpCasts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

We have recently migrated code from `Swift 2.3` to `4.0`.
The app working fine when run in debug mode on devices as well as simulators. No issues in compile and build.

But as soon as it is `archived`, it fails in compilation with the following error. And, more importantly, it is not pointing to any location (no file, no function, no statement) in the code.

Even I am finding difficulty in deducing - where and what the issue is.

It is built using `Xcode 9.0`. Previously I thought it is the issue of Beta version as I was using the `Beta` and `GM seed` of `XCode 9.0` on `Mac OS Sierra`.

```
Stored value type does not match pointer operand type!
  store i64 %119, %swift.bridge** %128, align 8, !dbg !402
 %swift.bridge*<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered during compilation; please file a bug report with your project and the crash log
<unknown>:0: note: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
0  swift                    0x000000010454adba PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000010454a1f6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffacd39b3a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000004 _sigtramp + 1395418340
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fffacbbe420 abort + 129
5  swift                    0x0000000100eb9fe7 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*)::$_0::__invoke(void*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 551
6  swift                    0x00000001045083fb llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 571
7  swift                    0x00000001045081ba llvm::report_fatal_error(char const*, bool) + 42
8  swift                    0x00000001044de6b6 (anonymous namespace)::VerifierLegacyPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 54
9  swift                    0x000000010448baaa llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 506
10 swift                    0x0000000104493609 llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 377
11 swift                    0x00000001044933fa llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 410
12 swift                    0x0000000101033778 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::DiagnosticEngine*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, swift::version::Version const&, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 5016
13 swift                    0x00000001010376d5 ThreadEntryPoint(swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int) + 181
14 swift                    0x000000010103772f void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int), swift::irgen::IRGenerator*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, int> >(void*) + 47
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffacd4393b _pthread_body + 180
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffacd43887 _pthread_body + 0
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x00007fffacd4308d thread_start + 13
Stack dump:
0.  Running pass 'Module Verifier' on function '@_T0s17_dictionaryUpCasts10DictionaryVyq0_q1_GACyxq_Gs8HashableRzsAFR0_r2_lFTfq4g_nSi_SQySayACyS2SGGGSiAHSgTg5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Swift code generation.

Select Project, go to your desired Target, and under build settings, you may try by changing code optimization level before you compile. Try whole-module-optimization with the respective configuration, as shown below:

[image]

With Swift 3.0 this is the default, and Swift 4.0 shouldn't be any different, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used Single-File Optimization, and it pointed out where & what the issue was.